# Visual Studio Extension Details from Microsoft Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I've got a list of visual studio extensions which I'm looping through so I can get the download URLs from the Microsoft service programmatically.

In one of the pieces of code, this is the endpoint that gives the details of the installed extensions.

`[https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/Services/dev12/Extension.svc][1]`

But when I put it in the browser, I get redirected to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/

This could be because the endpoint has been updated since.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

So the question is, is there an endpoint like above that I can query to get metadata like name, author, download Url etc. about VS extensions? If yes, what is it and how can I query it?

Comment: HI, what is your question?

Comment: @Stefan updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual Studio Extension Details from Microsoft Service

The destination for Visual Studio extensions (an installable unit that brings additional features to Visual Studio) has been the Visual Studio Gallery for a very long time. However, starting from November 2016, the Visual Studio Marketplace has become the one stop for all extensions of the Visual Studio Product Family.

The new site operates the same as the old gallery. You can browse, search, filter and download a `.vsix` extension to your machine and deploy it locally. As well, if you are signed in via your Microsoft account, you can rate and review the extensions.

Check [Microsoft DevOps Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/11/16/visual-studio-extensions-now-on-the-marketplace/) for some more details.

Besides, if you want to use the API for Visual Studio Marketplace to get metadata, I am afraid you can not do this thing at this moment. AFAIK, there is still not have a public VS marketplace API.

[Public REST API for Visual Studio Marketplace](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/331878-visual-studio-marketplace/suggestions/17623456-public-rest-api-for-visual-studio-marketplace)

Hope this helps.